# how to break the loop in db2 database

Tags: db2

i have created 1 procedure and used 1 cursor, using this cursor i have used to loop 
but that loop fetching from cursor is going to infinite loop. below my code for procedure.

```
    db2 "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEWEMPSELECT7 RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 
DECLARE OUTRATE VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE C1 CURSOR for 
SELECT Emp_name FROM NEWEMP WHERE Emp_id=100;
OPEN C1;
LOOP
FETCH FROM C1 INTO OUTRATE;
CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUTRATE);
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END"
```

The result is going to infinite loop. even i am not able to use C1%NOTFOUND or any keyword, because db2 doesnt support any keyword to break the rule.

please suggest how to break this loop in db2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning SQL PL, it will help you if you spend time studying the IBM [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.samptop.doc/doc/c0007609.html) programs and making them work for your environment.

Here is a trivial example based on your code, that works with the SAMPLE database on Db2-LUW:

Note that there are more elegant ways to code such loops, including using the WHILE statement, using SQLSCODE/SQLSTATE variables and comparisons of these etc.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEWEMPSELECT7 
RESULT SETS 1 LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE OUTRATE VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE v_at_end INTEGER default 0;
    DECLARE not_found CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR for 
        SELECT LASTNAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Empno=100;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not_found  SET v_at_end = 1 ;

    OPEN C1;
    fetch_loop:
    LOOP
        FETCH FROM C1 INTO OUTRATE;
        IF v_at_end <>0 THEN LEAVE fetch_loop; END IF;
        CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUTRATE);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
END
@
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter the language, when I create a loop that is potentially infinite, I always build an "emergency exit" into it. I've done this in C#, VB.Net, VBA, JAVA, and just now for the first time in an IBM DB2 SQL function.

Since the concept is valid in any language, I'll present it in pseudocode, as follows:

```
Begin Procedure

Declare Variable safety_counter As Integer

Begin loop
    ...
    <body of code>
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- this is your normal exit
        Exit Loop
    End If
    ...
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
    If safety_counter >= 1000             <-- set to any value you wish
        Exit Loop                         <-- this is the emergency exit
    End If
End Loop
```

Some variations are as follows.

If the loop is simple, the two exit criteria might be written in the same If-Then:

```
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- normal exit
    Or safety_counter >= 1000             <-- emergency exit
        Exit Loop
    End If
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
```

An error value might be returned like this:

```
Begin Procedure

Declare Variable result_value   As Integer
Declare Variable safety_counter As Integer

Begin loop
    ...
    <body of code>
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- this is your normal exit
        Set result_value = abc * xyz      <-- the value you seek          
        Exit Loop
    End If
    ...
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
    If safety_counter >= 1000             <-- set to any sufficient value
        Set result_value = (-123)         <-- indicate "infinite loop error"
        Exit Loop                         <-- this is the emergency exit
    End If
End Loop
Return result_value
```

There are many possible ways to do this, but the key is in safety_counter, and the way of monitoring it to trigger the emergency exit.

Comment: I mislike this.  At the very least, you need to **fault** if you take the safety valve, not simply exit, because if the input is legitimately more than your safety loop limit, you'll silently ignore input.  Which may cause far more havoc than a stuck loop.  This is besides the fact that in SQL, you should generally avoid explicit loops, and often cursors as well.

Comment: The safety value is variable, and not meant to be left in place forever, but sometimes I do leave it in, and set the value really high, like 1,000,000. For a fault, it's true that could be done, but that's what the negative return value is for. In the context of database functions, I don't want to have it keep stopping. I would rather have a weird value show up in a certain row/column. Then I could look at the complete results of the query, including other relevant columns, to diagnose the problem. The whole concept I laid out is just a loose framework, to be customized by the programmer.