# In DB2 SQL, how can I kill a recursive function call that's already stuck in an infinite loop..?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

If I have a DB2 SQL procedure or function that's recursive, or it has a tricky loop, and the process has become infinite, how can I kill it if it's already running..? This is DB2-for-i v7.3, with development in DBeaver SQL.

Is it enough to simply cancel the query in the SQL IDE..? I've done so in the past with too-long queries, and I always get a notification for "Query has been cancelled". But with an infinitely looping or recursing procedure, is there any risk the process might still continue in the background until something crashes and the DBA staff come to pound on my door with pitchforks and flaming torches..?

EDIT: It was suggested my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538273/how-to-break-the-loop-in-db2-database), but I read that one before my post, and it's not the same. That question is how to prevent an infinite loop from happening in the first place, but my question is about how to kill one that's already happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to break the loop in db2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538273/how-to-break-the-loop-in-db2-database)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Not that the answers to that question aren't useful in a preventative sort of way, but how do they answer this question where the code is already running and looping? You can't re-code the loop while the job is running, you have to cancel out of it somehow.

Comment: Yes. Preventing a loop isn't excessively difficult, but sometimes there's an "oops" and it takes off to infinity anyways. I wasn't asking how to prevent an infinite loop, but how to kill one that's already running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancel should work, but if you can find the right job in WRKACTJOB, then you can just end it with OPTION(*IMMED).

The server jobs should be in subsystem QUSRWRK, and are named QZDASOINIT. The one you are looking for will have your userid, and if it is looping, it will have a status of RUN. These jobs sit at TIMW normally when they are waiting for work. These are Prestart Jobs, and if you end one manually, it will come back if it needs to.

Comment: Ok, that's the sort of answer I was looking for. I do have Client Access "green screen" with limited admin rights. We used to have a private server and I had full rights to everything, but now we're "cloud based" with some shared resources, so I can't do as much. Now we have EDJ "Work with Job Queues" and EDU "Work with User Jobs". I'm assuming the latter is what I would use to find my SQL job (I'll have to play & see). If I kill that job, what's the scope? Is it just that session, my connection, me & others, or what..?

Comment: Each connection has it's own job. You will have to reconnect dBeaver if you end it's server job. If you have access to iNavigator, you can do it from there as well.

Comment: Ok. DBeaver is pretty dynamic with its connections; it connects when it needs to with no intervention, and I have mine set to leave the connection open unless I purposely disconnect or recycle it. Unfortunately my rights in iNav were restricted almost to nothing when we moved to the cloud (#grumble). It's with good reason though, we share space with other customers, and of course can't have customers able to see & change each other's resources.

Answer (score -1):

Build a cancel into the loop by some means to exit a long running loop.

--for example checking if any rows exist in a table.

```
loop...
set myexit = (select myexit from myexit fetch first 1 rows only);
if myexit is not null then return;
endloop...
```

Maybe some better solutions come of this.

Comment: The answer is Build a cancel in the loop.  Or in ISERIES terminology check the shut down indicator each loop and gracefully exit when *ON.